# HTTPS session cookie and post security with PHP

Tags: php, cookies, https

I am using https with php and have a few security questions:

+I saw this link:

["secure" parameter in session_set_cookie_params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441642/php-session-set-cookie-params)

Does this mean even though the secure flag is set with a cookie, it only lets the client pass it to a https address? If the cookie contains the session_id, should I encrypt it before sending from the server and then decrypt it when receiving it?

+When I login to a https address from a https page, firefox shows the plain text password in POST data. Is this a security risk? Also can I put the form on a regular http page without a security risk?

UPDATE: what I'm trying to do is prevent session hijacking. Should I just not send any cookies containing session_ids over http? It's a kohana script I'm working on and it seems to start the session even if not logged in. I'm thinking of checking for https before session_start();

Comment: Where is Firefox showing the plain text password in post data? Do you have an extension that is showing you what data has been POSTed?

Comment: php manual states, 'secure' Indicates that the cookie should only be transmitted over a secure HTTPS connection from the client

Comment: if your action is using https, then its sending it encrypted, if not it's in the clear

Comment: On the first page visit the cookie containing the session id is sent over http. From what I read the server will only accept the cookie again if it is sent over https? Should I not send cookies over http, or regenerate a new session_id on each page request to prevent hijacking, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can securely submit data from a form accessed via HTTP, as long as the POST action submits to an HTTPS URL.

Putting the form on an HTTPS page is a best practice for feel good reasons for the user, because people may be skeptical of submitting secure information in a form if page displaying the form does not show that they are connected via HTTPS.

Comment: It's httpfox that's showing the post data. It does the same with gmail so I guess its not an issue. Thanks.

Comment: What I did was regenerate the session_id after login and added code to prevent access to non-ssl pages if a session exists.